# Plotting epicycles by using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, visualization

Why does the following code not working?

I want to display epicycles by using *matplotlib* like a following image

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import math


freqList = [1,2,3]
ampList = [1,2,4]
phaseList = [0,10,20]

circles = [] #create list of circles

x = 0
y = 0
for i in range(len(freqList)):
   prevx = x
   prevy = y
   theta = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 )
   x += ampList[i] * np.cos( theta*freqList[i] + phaseList[i] )
   y += ampList[i] * np.sin( theta*freqList[i] + phaseList[i] )

   circle = plt.Circle((prevx, prevy), ampList[i], fill=False)
   circles.append(circle)

   plt.figure()
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.add_patch(circles[i])
   plt.axis("equal")
   plt.xlim( -10 , 10 ) 
   plt.ylim( -10 , 10 ) 
   plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied some changes to your code:

- loop over elements of a list with `for i in range(len(list_name))` and then get i<sup>th</sup> element with `list_name[i]` works, but it is a little awkward; in python you can loop over elements of list directly: `for element in list`. If you need to loop over element of more than one list, you can use `zip`: `for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)`
- within your loop you generates the circles, once at a time, and add it to the plot. Things which are created only once (not once every cycle) have to be generated outside the for loop; that's the case for `fig`, `ax` etc.
- in your code you have created an array, `theta`, which is 150 elements. Inside for loop you add up a function of `theta`, which is an array too, to `x` and `y`. So, in the first iteration `x` and `y` are `int` and represent coordinates of the first circle, then they become  arrays. This is the reason why your code throws an error
- if you use [**`matplotlib.patches.Circle`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) you need only the coordinates of the center and the radius. No need to compute theta, no need to use `freqList` (if I interpreted it correctly). For this reason, inside the loop you have only to pass current center coordinates and radius to [**`matplotlib.patches.Circle`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) and compute center coordinates for the next circle using only current amplitude and phase

That being said, your code becomes:

```
# import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# amplitude and phase definition
ampList = [1,2,4]
phaseList = [0,10,20]

# center coordinates of the first circle
C_x = 0
C_y = 0

# generate figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# loop over each amplitude and phase
for amp, phase in zip(ampList, phaseList):

    # draw current circle
    circle = plt.Circle((C_x, C_y), amp, fill = False)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
    # draw current circle center
    ax.plot(C_x, C_y, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'k', markeredgecolor = 'k')

    # compute next circle center 
    C_x += amp*np.cos(np.deg2rad(phase))
    C_y += amp*np.sin(np.deg2rad(phase))

# adjust axis
plt.axis("equal")
plt.xlim( -10 , 10 )
plt.ylim( -10 , 10 )

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]